# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, +). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the current context

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, circular-dependency, nestjs

having some problems, di/circular-references I'm sure I'm doing wrong, I just can't see it.

Any help would be much appreciated

user.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
        forwardRef(() => AuthModule)
    ],
    providers: [ UserService, TokenService ],
    exports: [ UserService ]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [ forwardRef(() => UserModule) ],
    controllers: [ AuthController ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        UserService,
        TokenService
    ],
    exports: [ AuthService, TokenService ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I get [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'module' of undefined.

Was originally having "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService. I then deleted the UserModule entirely and just used the AuthModule, everything worked, then decided to add the UserModule back in today and move the code from AuthModule back into the UserModule, then discovered the forwardRef(() => ) and now I'm getting the cannot read property 'model'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include the `import`s part of your code?

Comment: Why `UserService` is defined in the `AuthModule`?

Comment: I've tried different things, that's the state that I ended up with a different error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to inject the (circular) dependencies of the `UserService` via `forwardRef` as well, see the [CommonService example](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency):

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => TokenService)) private readonly tokenService: TokenService) {}
```

Also, providers should only be declared in one module. If you want to use them in another module, export those providers and then just import the module: `UserModule` imports `AuthModule` and does **not** provide the `AuthService` again. This way all exported providers can be used in the `UserModule`.

So, remove the `UserService` from the `AuthModule`'s providers list and the `TokenService` from the `UserModule`.

Comment: In the docs they pointed to use one and not them combined

Answer (score 4):

In case, you got above error when adding the repository to the service with `TypeORM`, then add below code in the module file

```
imports: [
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([<your-entity>])
],
```

Answer (score -1):

I got error when I have   2 consecutive commas in providers of my array

```
  providers: [
    AService,
    BService,, // <- NOT ALLOWED CIRCULAR PROBLEM 
  ],
```

Comment: You can use tools like prettier, eslint/tslint to avoid this